# Что написать в .htaccess и конфиг yii2 basic для дефолтной маршрутизации?

Tags: .htaccess, yii2

Есть стандартный скелет сайта на базе шаблона `yii-basic`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что нужно написать в `.htaccess`, где его расположить, чтобы можно было спокойно заходить на сайт `mysite.ru` и видеть главную страницу, а при обращении через слэш `mysite.ru/controller`, чтоб меня направляло в контроллер и было, к примеру:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И что написать в конфиге?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все довольно просто. Нехитрая инструкция написана **[здесь](https://github.com/ilopX/yii2-basic-htaccess)**

Итак три шага:

- Создаем `.htaccess` в самом корне сайта (там где лежат все все все папки) и пишем следующее:

  ```
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      Options +FollowSymlinks
      RewriteEngine On
  </IfModule>

  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/.*
      RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1 [L]

      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web/
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteRule ^.*$ web/index.php
  </IfModule>
  ```
- Идем в папку `web`, создаем еще один `.htaccess` и пишем туда:

  ```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . index.php
  ```
- Открываем конфигурационный файл `/config/web.php`

  ```
  'request' => [
      'baseUrl' => '',
  ],
  'urlManager' => [
      'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
      'showScriptName' => false,
      'rules' => [
          '' => 'site/index',
          '<action>'=>'site/<action>',
      ],
  ],
  ```

`baseUrl = ''` - убираем назойливый `web` в ссылке

`enablePrettyUrl` - использование красивых ссылок (чпу)

`showScriptName' => false,` - скрыть в ссылке `index.php`

В дальнейшем правила `'' => 'site/index'` и `'<action>'=>'site/<action>',` можно будет переопределить так, как вам захочется. Но для начала этого хватит.

Радуемся!