# urlManager, yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Как сделать вместо ссылок вида

> category/album?id=10

Ссылки вида -

> category/album/10

Я так понимаю нужно настраивать urlManager в конфиге, но как?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/517860/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-htaccess-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B3-yii2-basic-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%88%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8  должно помочь

Comment: там htacces , оно вроде не связано с urlManager. Мне нужно сделать без get параметра ?id= ..

Comment: внимательно читайте.......

Comment: спасибо, уже решил

Comment: Если что, то в документации подобные вещи хорошо описаны: [Использование человекопонятных URL](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/runtime-routing.md#Использование-человекопонятных-url-) + [Рекомендуемые настройки Apache](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/start-installation.md#Рекомендуемые-настройки-apache-) (там же [Nginx](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/start-installation.md#Рекомендуемые-настройки-nginx-))

Answer (score 0):

Может нужно будет кому-то

```
'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',

            ],
        ],
```

Comment: Вот только это не сработает если вы уберете `enablePrettyUrl => true`....... что как раз написано в ответе, который я вам дал

Comment: возможно, у меня так было просто, до этого делал что-то