# В какую папку ставить YII2?

Tags: yii2

На сервере есть папка пользователя, в ней папка с доменом будущего сайта, например `site.com`.

В папку пользователя ставлю composer и говорю при установке ставить фреймворк в папку `site.com`. Он ставится и я вижу что `index.php` и `robots.txt` не в `site.com` а в `site.com/web` Выходит надо перенастраивать веб-сервер теперь чтобы он смотрел в другую папку? а именно `site.com/web` ?

Comment: да, всё  так. нужно в корень сайта, а также в папку `web` положить `htaccess` с перенаправлением....... пример тут: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/517861/191482

Comment: @Алексей-Шиманский спасибо, помогло, как ответ бы делали

Comment: могу только закрыть как дубликат :D

Comment: @Алексей-Шиманский можно конечно )) Просто у того вопроса такое название сложное и в списке похожих его не было

Comment: Если есть предложение по более легкому заголовку буду только рад ибо мучился что писать

Comment: @Алексей-Шиманский Папка для установки YII2? Корневая директория YII2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, вы всё правильно подметили: в корень сайта, а также в папку `web` нужно положить файл `.htaccess` с перенаправлением:

В корне сайта:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ web/index.php
</IfModule>
```

В папке web:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Дефолтная настройка маршрутизации `yii2`, включая конфигурацию `htaccess` можно прочитать в ветке по `yii2`, а именно в **[данном](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/517861/191482)** ответе.