# Не работает .htaccess yii2

Tags: yii2, .htaccess, url, чпу, basic

Скачал Basic yii2 , создал 2 файла .htaccess, один в корне сайта, другой в папке веб, при переходе на стартовый шаблон он заходит , но при переходе по пунктам меню он выдает ошибку "Not Found

The requested URL /index.phpï»¿ was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.10 (Unix) Server at site.ser588nn.beget.tech Port 80"

Код .htaccess в корневой папке:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(web)
RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ /web/assets/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)& web/css/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^js/(.*)& web/js/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)& web/images/$1 [L]
RewriteRule (.*) /web/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /web/index.php
```

Код .htaccess в папке web:

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . index.php﻿
```

И код в папке config файле web.php(настраивается ЧПУ):

```
<?php

$params = require(__DIR__ . '/params.php');
$db = require(__DIR__ . '/db.php');

$config = [
    'id' => 'basic',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'components' => [
        'request' => [
            // !!! insert a secret key in the following (if it is empty) - this is required by cookie validation
            'cookieValidationKey' => 'asdas123',
            'baseUrl' => '',
        ],
        'cache' => [
            'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
        ],
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        ],
        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ],
        'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            // send all mails to a file by default. You have to set
            // 'useFileTransport' to false and configure a transport
            // for the mailer to send real emails.
            'useFileTransport' => true,
        ],
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'db' => $db,

        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
            ],
        ],

    ],
    'params' => $params,
];

if (YII_ENV_DEV) {
    // configuration adjustments for 'dev' environment
    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'debug';
    $config['modules']['debug'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\debug\Module',
        // uncomment the following to add your IP if you are not connecting from localhost.
        //'allowedIPs' => ['127.0.0.1', '::1'],
    ];

    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'gii';
    $config['modules']['gii'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\gii\Module',
        // uncomment the following to add your IP if you are not connecting from localhost.
        //'allowedIPs' => ['127.0.0.1', '::1'],
    ];
}

return $config;
```

Comment: а кто такой `index.phpï`?

Comment: такую ошибку выдает, я не сам это придумал

Comment: то есть расширение у index файла верное у тебя?

Comment: Да, это готовый шаблон с официального сайта yii2

Comment: я конечно не совсем уверен, но попробуй сделать настройки в htaccess как тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/517861/191482

Comment: Да все заработало, постоянно об этот htaccess спотыкаюсь)