# Не работает ЧПУ в yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Хочу сделать ЧПУ на yii2. Сделал всё по инструкции, но ничего не работает, к тому же отображается только главная страница, а остальные (about, contact, login) - нет, выдаётся ошибка 404. Подскажите, что может быть не так?
Содержимое корневого .htaccess:

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^(.+)?$ /web/$1
```

Содержимое web/.htaccess:

```
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . index.php
```

Содержимое config/web.php:

```
    <?php

    $params = require __DIR__ . '/params.php';
    $db = require __DIR__ . '/db.php';

    $config = [
        'id' => 'basic',
        'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
        'bootstrap' => ['log'],
        'aliases' => [
            '@bower' => '@vendor/bower-asset',
            '@npm'   => '@vendor/npm-asset',
        ],
        'components' => [
        'request' => [
                // !!! insert a secret key in the following (if it is empty) - this is required by cookie validation
               'cookieValidationKey' => 'cukfdukfudytdgfcfxrt',
               //'baseUrl' => '',
          ],
         'cache' => [
              'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
          ],
          'user' => [
          'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
          'enableAutoLogin' => true,
         ],
         'errorHandler' => [
              'errorAction' => 'site/error',
            ],
         'mailer' => [
              'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
              // send all mails to a file by default. You have to set
              // 'useFileTransport' to false and configure a transport
              // for the mailer to send real emails.
              'useFileTransport' => true,
          ],
          'log' => [
              'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
              'targets' => [
                 [
                       'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                       'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                 ],
               ],
            ],
           'db' => $db,

           'urlManager' => [
           'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
           'showScriptName' => false,
           'rules' => [
             ],
          ],

      ],
'params' => $params,
  ];

  if (YII_ENV_DEV) {
// configuration adjustments for 'dev' environment
$config['bootstrap'][] = 'debug';
$config['modules']['debug'] = [
    'class' => 'yii\debug\Module',
    // uncomment the following to add your IP if you are not connecting from localhost.
    //'allowedIPs' => ['127.0.0.1', '::1'],
];

$config['bootstrap'][] = 'gii';
$config['modules']['gii'] = [
    'class' => 'yii\gii\Module',
    // uncomment the following to add your IP if you are not connecting from localhost.
    //'allowedIPs' => ['127.0.0.1', '::1'],
];
 }

   return $config;
```

Comment: А разве не папка web должна быть корнем сайта!? А еще у вас сервер может не apache.

Comment: Не знал, что папка web должна быть корнем сайта. Большое спасибо.

Comment: Даже если сервер Apache, в нем может быть отключена обработка htaccess, за это отвечает директива AllowOverride. Приведите конфиг host'а

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что написать в .htaccess и конфиг yii2 basic для дефолтной маршрутизации?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/517860/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2-htaccess-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%b3-yii2-basic-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%88%d1%80%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8)

Comment: Поместил папку web в виртуальный хост, помогло. Всем спасибо за ответы!

Answer (score 1):

в корне. Правила сразу с переводом на https (автоматически сработает, если будет защищённое соединение)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^web/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ web/index.php

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

В папке web

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

в `config/web.php` нужно раскомментировать (у вас не так в примере) строку `'baseUrl' => '',`

Там же нужно добавить правила. Например:

```
'rules' => [
    '<action:(about|contact|login|)>' => '/site/<action>',
    '<controller>/<action>' => '<controller>/<action>',
],
```

Отмечу, что все экшены (кроме `actionIndex`) на страницы нужно указывать через `|`. Всё.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно добавить в urlManager правила. И только тогда все заработает. Как Вы хотите чтобы yii2 само знало какие страницы по какому адресу отображать. В 'rules' нужно указать все ето.
'желаемый_адрес' => 'контроллер/действие'

Answer (score 0):

В моем случае не работало из-за настроек nginx (mac OS).
В файле настроек сервера по адресу:
/usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

строка:
*try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;*

```
location / {
        # Перенаправляем все запросы к несуществующим директориям и файлам на 
        index.php
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
```