# Yii2 - не работает ЧПУ

Tags: yii2, seo, чпу

То ли новая версия вышла, то ли что не пойму, делаю все как здесь: [Не работает ЧПУ в yii2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/758391/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%A7%D0%9F%D0%A3-%D0%B2-yii2), но ничего не срабатывает и просто выдается 404 Not Found. Что может быть упущено?

Comment: Надо еще код добавить. Конфиг как минимум. Настройки хоста тоже не помешает.

Comment: и в апаче включить AllowOverride = All