# В чём проблема 404 при роутинге Yii2?

Tags: yii2, роутинг

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
        '/' => 'site/index',
        'about' => 'site/about',
        'contact' => 'site/contact',
        'login' => 'site/login',
     ],
```

Выполняю банальный роутинг, перехожу на http://magazin.ru/login локального сервера, получаю 404.

Comment: а в контроллере есть такой метод? а все htaccess настроены?

Comment: Делаю по инструкции http://www.webapplex.ru/routing-v-yii-2.x-urlmanager . Что должно быть в htaccess?

Comment: В логах сервера что? В логах Yii2?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/517860/191482   базовая маршутизация